# Assigning info to a table and creating an auto incremented id... How to get that newly created id?

Tags: php, mysqli, get, addition

I have a block of code that stores some basic user choices inside of a mysql table.

```
    $isACompany = $_POST['isACompany'];
    $hasDifBilling = $_POST['hasDifBilling'];
    $stmt = $link->prepare("
        INSERT INTO user_info SET
        id='',
        isACompany = ?,
        hasDifBilling = ?'
    ");
    if (!$stmt)
    {
        $error = "{$link->errno}  :  {$link->error}";
        include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
        exit();
    }
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("ii", $isACompany, $hasDifBilling))
    {
        $error = "{$stmt->errno}  :  {$stmt->error}";
        include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
        exit();
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute())
    {
        $error = "{$stmt->errno}  :  {$stmt->error}";
        include "$docRoot/html/main/error.html.php";
        exit();
    }
```

Given that code, how would I obtain the newly created id in this instance?

I have another question relating to this code too, although it is not part of the question its self... As the first two variables draw out the values of those two posts, and seeing as those values are hard coded into the html and selected by a checkbox (either "1" or "" which is 0). Would I still need to sanitize them before adding the information to the database?

Comment: [Read `$stmt->insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php)

Comment: @Michael It's a property, not a method ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom I should learn to read my own doc links.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question - _any_ value that comes in `$_POST` (or the other user input methods) must be sanitized or better, passed as a param in a prepared statement.  As an end user, I could easily fake a value that isn't the one you hard-coded in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, but could you please provide me with a simple example of this... Im a bit confused of its use, although it seems to be exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: @Michael Wow thats interesting, would you be able to provide me with some links that explain this and how it is done further? I am referring to how a user could actually fake something like that.

Comment: @BlackberryFan There are a few good reference questions on SO here (which I can't ever seen to find when I look). Basically, you need to think of your HTML as totally decoupled from the back-end code.  The values posted to your backend script don't have to come from your form - any form (legitimate or otherwise) could post the correctly named inputs to your script and it wouldn't know the difference (absent some other kind of special uniquely identifying value like an XSS token)

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the reply, and I am  actually building a simple e-commerce... This makes me kind of scared that I lack the fundamental knowledge to accomplish this project correctly! I am now scared :) But i do understand that you are getting at, so thank you for the enlightenment!

Comment: @BlackberryFan Well, you're on the right track using prepared statements here.  If you are not using prepared statements everywhere, expand your code to use them wherever the query receives _any_ user input.

Comment: @Micheal, well this is basically what I am trying to accomplish, I am re-writing the code to include the use of mysqli prepared statements. What I was unsure of is whether this would be enough. I do have a function that strips tags and escapes content if needed... But now in not sure whether this is supposed to be used or not anymore. If i was dealing with text input, I should sanitize the input before adding it as the variable to be prepared? or is that just a waste of time?

Comment: @BlackberryFan Stripping tags and sanitizing the data itself is abstracted from the "escaping" that using prepared statements accomplishes. Prepared statements make it safe for you to insert the data into the database, but that is it - it does not prevent, for example, XSS attacks - you still need to sanitise the input in other ways, and it is best to do this before you insert it, rather than doing it on the fly every time you select it.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you, you make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael correctly pointed out, the ID of the row you inserted can be retrieved using the [`$stmt->insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php) property.

The more important part of this question is the second part, and the answer to that is a big fat **YES** you *must* escape everything that comes from user input! Just because you "hard-coded" it into the HTML, does not mean the user is unable to manipulate this. There are a million and one ways to do it - [Javascript injection](http://www.testingsecurity.com/how-to-test/injection-vulnerabilities/Javascript-Injection) and "spoof" HTTP requests to name but two.

You **must** escape *anything* that comes from the client. Always. End of story.

Comment: Thanks a lot! so simply calling the property will return the id that was just created? And as for the second part, I find that quite interesting :) As a side question though, would my use of prepared statements be sufficient in this instance? This is as michael mentions this being the better solution?